# $\mu$-completion of $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Rudin shows that $\mu$ is well-defined on $\mathfrak{M}^*$. But this little bit confuses me since well-defined of function I understand in the following meaning: $f:X\to Y$ is well-defined if $x=y$ then $f(x)=f(y)$. But Rudin says it in different manner.

Can anyone please explain it to me clearly? Would be very grateful for answer.

**EDIT:** I guess that he must to prove that if $E,S$ are sets such that $A\subset E\subset B$ and $A\subset S\subset B$ with $\mu(B-A)=0$ then $\mu(E)=\mu(S)$. Am I right?

Comment: What you say in your edit is okay on its own, but not the essential thing. It is more the trivial observation that inspires to extend the measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there are measurable subsets $A,B$ and next to that some set $E$ with $A\subseteq E\subseteq B$.

If $\mu(B-A)=0$ (and automatically $\mu A=\mu B$) then it is quite tempting to say that also $E$ can be labeled to be a set having measure $\mu A=\mu B$. That is the inspiration for "defining" $\mu^*(E)=\mu(A)=\mu(B)$.

But wait a minute... What if later I meet measurable sets $A',B'$ again with $A'\subseteq E\subseteq B'$ and $\mu(B'-A')=0$, but this with $\mu(A)\neq\mu(A')$?

Then with the same arguing I come to $\mu^*(E)=\mu(A')$ wich contradicts $\mu^*(E)=\mu(A)$.

Then apparantly $\mu^*$ is not well defined then.

To come to the conclusion that $\mu^*$ *is* well defined it must be shown that the sketched scenario will not appear.

Comment: But what's wrong with my edit? Well-defined of measure confuses me very  hard :( Still the second day can't understand it

Comment: Btw very nice and clear answer! +1.

Comment: Persevere. As I said: nothing is wrong with what you say in your edit, but does it  exclude the scenario that I sketched in my answer? No. So it does not prove "well defined".

Comment: "but does it exclude the scenario that I sketched in my answer? No." Can you explain it please?

Comment: What you say in your edit simply *does not exclude* the existence of two pairs $(A_i,B_i)$ of measurable sets with $A_i\subseteq E\subseteq B_i$ and $\mu(B_i-A_i)=0$ and $\mu A_1\neq\mu A_2$. In your edit you have $A,B$ fixed and $E$ somehow variable. You must look at the opposite: $E$ fixed and $A,B$ variable.

Comment: But does you answer include what did I say in my edit?

Comment: If the content of your edit would not be true then it would be quite easy to show that $\mu$ cannot be extended in a proper way. A well defined extension would not be possible then. In that sense it is a **necessary** (and inspiring) condition. In the theorem it is shown (and this the whole issue) that the condition is **also sufficient**. In my answer I do not repeat the proof of Rudin.

Comment: Let me ask you one more question. Words necessary and sufficient condition seems unknown

Comment: If $p$ implies $q$ then $p$ is a sufficient condition for $q$ and conversely $q$ is a necessary condition for $p$. Note that $p$ cannot be a true statement if $q$ is not true. So for that it is *necessary* that $q$ is true. However, if $q$ is true then you are not allowed to draw the conclusion that $p$ is true as well. The fact that $q$ is true is *not sufficient* for that.

Comment: So your statement is stronger than mine?

Comment: The statement made in your edit on its own is not enough to conclude that $\mu$ can be extended in a proper way. I am not making any statements myself. Rudin does that and shows that $\mu$ can be extended in a proper way.

Comment: I mean that Rudin's idea is more stronger than mine and include my "edit"?

Comment: Rudin doesn't even mentions the content of your edit, since it is a triviality.

Comment: But what about if Rudin's idea holds but my is not. May it happen?

Comment: No. What you say in your edit *does hold*. I stop with this discussion now.

Comment: Thank for help! I will think on this myself